# mosquitto rejects all connections if crlfile is used

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using the latest (2.0.14) mosquitto version on debian 11.

I am using certificates for authentication and want to include a crl file.
This is my config /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/my.conf:

```
per_listener_settings true

listener 8883
bind_address 0.0.0.0
#bind_port = 8883
allow_anonymous false

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.cert
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt
require_certificate true
use_subject_as_username true

crlfile /etc/mosquitto/my-crlfile
```

When I try to send a message to the server I get this error.
Client `OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca`
Server `OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed`

When I remove the crlfile line from the config everthing works fine.

This is the content of /etc/mosquitto/my-crlfile

```
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----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-----END X509 CRL-----
```

It does not contain any certificates so far, adding on ends up with the same result.

To be sure I check with openssl.

```
openssl verify -CRLfile ../MyOrg.crl -CAfile ../MyOrg-RootCA.crt -verbose my.cert

my.cert: OK
```

There is a simular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242005/mosquitto-blocks-all-connections-when-using-crl-file) but it does not seam to be the same problem.

The CRL File is generated from a java application so the next update will always be one day in the future, and the last update one day in the past.

Update: Adding `-crl_check` to the openssl commands gives me an error.

```
openssl verify -crl_check -CRLfile ../MyOrg.crl -CAfile ../MyOrg-RootCA.crt -verbose my.cert

C = CU, ST = ST, L = Location, O = company, OU = CTS, CN = raspberry-pi 4 5426
error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error my.cert: verification failed
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a CRL file (besides the fact your question is offtopic here as not related to programming)? You understand a CRL file is a list of *revoked* certificates that shouldn't be trusted. This is less and less used nowadays, in the presence of very limited in duration certificates. The unknown ca alert means the receiving part got a certificate or certificate revocation signed by a CA it doesn't know about. If you can remove the CRL file that is certainly the simplest path forward.

Comment: The CRL you pasted in the question has "Next update" set to "Sat Jul 23 10:10:57 UTC 2022" which may help you understand the fix in the previous question (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70242005/11810946) and [more info here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20961)).

Comment: @Brits the crl file is generated with java, and next update gets always set to now + 1d.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I posted the question here because of the reference to the other question where I can't apply the answer and my crl is also generated via java. The receiving part does not know about the crl list where should it know if the crl is signed.

Comment: @AceofSpade so you are updating the file every day. I don't think Mosquitto will pick up changes automatically (see [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/35)). Please confirm when you performed your test and if the Mosquitto config had been reloaded (restart or SIGHUP).

Comment: @Brits I want to but I was not able to test it yet because all connections are rejected. At the moment I restart mosquitto when I changed the crl.